# Suppressing known errors in android strict mode

Tags: android-strictmode

I am trying to implement strict mode in android and my use case is I want to suppress the known errors which cant be fixed and let the app to crash on new scenarios.  Is there anything like lint-baseline where I can add the known strict mode errors and suppress it with more specification like line number and error type ?

I am trying to suppress known android strict mode errors